# Connect an interactive html form to a sql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I'm trying to create an html form to provide information about the salaries table in my database, the user should be able to pick year between 1986-1996 and choose if she wants to see the total salary of that year or the average salary of that year.

I have no idea how I link up these scripts and I can't find much online.

html file:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <fieldset>
        <form id="frmName" method=post action="Oppgave4.php" onsubmit="">
        <h1>Oppgave 4</h1>
            Choose year:
            <select id="frmName" onChange="">
                <option selected disabled hidden>----</option>
                <option name="1986">1986</option>
                <option name="1987">1987</option>
                <option name="1988">1988</option>
                <option name="1989">1989</option>
                <option name="1990">1990</option>
                <option name="1991">1991</option>
                <option name="1992">1992</option>
                <option name="1993">1993</option>
                <option name="1994">1994</option>
                <option name="1995">1995</option>
                <option name="1996">1996</option>
            </select>
            Total or average salary:
            <select id="frmName" onChange="">
                <option selected disabled hidden>----</option>
                <option name="Total">Total salary</option>
                <option name="Average">Average salary</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
            </p>
        </form>
        </fieldset>
    </body>
</html>
```

php file:

```
<?php
$year = ($_POST['1986'], $_POST['1987'], $_POST['1988'], $_POST['1989'], $_POST['1990'],
$_POST['1991'], $_POST['1992'], $_POST['1993'], $_POST['1994'], $_POST['1995'],
 $_POST['1996'], $_POST['Total']);
$average = $_POST['Average'];

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "employees");

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sqlavg = "SELECT AVG(salaries.salary) AS average FROM salaries
WHERE from_date = '$year'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if (!empty($result) && $result->num_rows > 0) {

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<tr><td>" . $row["average"] ."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

$sqlsum = "SELECT SUM(salaries.salary) AS total FROM salaries
WHERE from_date = '$year'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if (!empty($result) && $result->num_rows > 0) {

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<tr><td>" . $row["total"] ."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

} else { echo "0 results"; }
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: `<select id="frmName" onChange="">` needs a `name` attribute, ie. `<select id="frmName" onChange="" name="year">` You can then access `$_POST['year']` in your script. `<option>` doesn't have a `name` attribute. (As well as your other `<select>`)

Comment: A basic HTML/PHP forms tutorial would show you what to do. Compare your version carefully with the demonstrations you find.

Comment: P.S. **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: Also **Never** get your web app to login to the database as root. Root can do whatever it likes,
so on top of the SQL injection vulnerabilities
this just leaves your database an open book for hackers.
Instead create a separate user account specifically for this application which has only the permissions it actually _needs_ in order to work properly.
Don't even use the root account as a shortcut during development or testing, because you need to test your account permissions as well - otherwise when you go live you might have unexpected errors relating to the user account setup.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is literally PHP/MySQL 101 and there is a lot online on how to do this. Having said that you are making some mistakes in your code. First, you should name the `<select>`

```
<select name="year">
```

Then you should give each option a value:

```
<option value="1994">1994</option>
...// do each one like this
```

This way, when the form is submitted to the PHP you can find it in the POST array:

```
$year = $_POST['year'];
```

That is just a start. You have a second drop-down that also needs a name and each option should have a value attribute.

```
<select name="calculation_type">
     <option>----</option>
     <option value="Total">Total salary</option>
     <option value="Average">Average salary</option>
</select>
```

Which will be found like this in the POST array:

```
$average = $_POST['calculation_type'];
```

Your form needs a name and does not need the `onsubmit` The action should be the name of the PHP script which will perform the calculations:

```
<form name="form_name" method=post action="Oppgave4.php">
```

**Warning**

[Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

**Suggestion**

You should go work through some basic PHP tutorials like those offered by https://www.learn-php.org/ (a free, interactive website) or other services